# R code optimalization for reading a huge amount of csv files

Tags: r, database, bigdata

I'm right now working on a microscopy project, where I read in the results from CSV files. I have 8 screen directories (screen_01- screen_08), each of them contains a lot of files. I need 4 information from the files (Screen number from directory name, 3 info from the file names), and the next X column is from the lines of the CSV. I've made a test dataset, only contains 123 files, to test my code, but for this amount of files, the code runs for more than an hour. My whole dataset contains 3600+ files. Could you help me improve my code?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

custom_headers <-c("file name","screen number","well","field of view","id","NUCLEUS METCENTER-X","NUCLEUS METCENTER-Y","NUCLEUS AREA","NUCLEUS CIRCULARITY","NUCLEUS CONVEXITY","NUCLEUS ELLIPSE-ECCENTRICITY","NUCLEUS ELLIPSE-MAJOR AXIS LENGTH","NUCLEUS ELLIPSE-MINOR AXIS LENGTH","NUCLEUS ELLIPSE-ORIENT","NUCLEUS ENCLOSING CIRCLE RADIUS","NUCLEUS EXTENT","NUCLEUS FORM FACTOR","NUCLEUS HARALICK TEXTURE-1 DAPI 0 3","NUCLEUS HARALICK TEXTURE-2 DAPI 0 3","NUCLEUS HARALICK TEXTURE-3 DAPI 0 3","NUCLEUS HARALICK TEXTURE-4 DAPI 0 3","NUCLEUS HARALICK TEXTURE-5 DAPI 0 3","NUCLEUS HARALICK TEXTURE-6 DAPI 0 3","NUCLEUS HARALICK TEXTURE-7 DAPI 0 3","NUCLEUS HARALICK TEXTURE-8 DAPI 0 3","NUCLEUS HARALICK TEXTURE-9 DAPI 0 3","NUCLEUS HARALICK TEXTURE-10 DAPI 0 3","NUCLEUS HARALICK TEXTURE-11 DAPI 0 3","NUCLEUS HARALICK TEXTURE-12 DAPI 0 3","NUCLEUS HU MOMENTS-1","NUCLEUS HU MOMENTS-2","NUCLEUS HU MOMENTS-3","NUCLEUS HU MOMENTS-4","NUCLEUS HU MOMENTS-5","NUCLEUS HU MOMENTS-6","NUCLEUS HU MOMENTS-7","NUCLEUS LCAVITY","NUCLEUS NUMBER OF COMPONENTS","NUCLEUS PERIMETER","NUCLEUS REAL DIAMETER","NUCLEUS REAL PERIMETER","NUCLEUS SOLIDITY","NUCLEUS SPHERICITY","NUCLEUS VOLUMETRY","NUCLEUS WINDOWED-INTENSITY-INTEGRATED DAPI","NUCLEUS WINDOWED-INTENSITY-MAX DAPI","NUCLEUS WINDOWED-INTENSITY-MEAN DAPI","NUCLEUS WINDOWED-INTENSITY-MEDIAN DAPI","NUCLEUS WINDOWED-INTENSITY-MIN DAPI","NUCLEUS WINDOWED-INTENSITY-STDDEV DAPI","CELL METCENTER-X","CELL METCENTER-Y","CELL AREA,CELL CIRCULARITY","CELL CONVEXITY","CELL ELLIPSE-ECCENTRICITY","CELL ELLIPSE-MAJOR AXIS LENGTH","CELL ELLIPSE-MINOR AXIS LENGTH","CELL ELLIPSE-ORIENT","CELL ENCLOSING CIRCLE RADIUS","CELL EXTENT","CELL FORM FACTOR","CELL HARALICK TEXTURE-1 FM4-64 0 3","CELL HARALICK TEXTURE-2 FM4-64 0 3","CELL HARALICK TEXTURE-3 FM4-64 0 3","CELL HARALICK TEXTURE-4 FM4-64 0 3","CELL HARALICK TEXTURE-5 FM4-64 0 3","CELL HARALICK TEXTURE-6 FM4-64 0 3","CELL HARALICK TEXTURE-7 FM4-64 0 3","CELL HARALICK TEXTURE-8 FM4-64 0 3","CELL HARALICK TEXTURE-9 FM4-64 0 3","CELL HARALICK TEXTURE-10 FM4-64 0 3","CELL HARALICK TEXTURE-11 FM4-64 0 3","CELL HARALICK TEXTURE-12 FM4-64 0 3","CELL HU MOMENTS-1","CELL HU MOMENTS-2","CELL HU MOMENTS-3","CELL HU MOMENTS-4","CELL HU MOMENTS-5","CELL HU MOMENTS-6","CELL HU MOMENTS-7","CELL LCAVITY","CELL PERIMETER","CELL REAL DIAMETER","CELL REAL PERIMETER","CELL SOLIDITY","CELL SPHERICITY","CELL VOLUMETRY","CELL WINDOWED-INTENSITY-INTEGRATED FM4-64","CELL WINDOWED-INTENSITY-MAX FM4-64","CELL WINDOWED-INTENSITY-MEAN FM4-64","CELL WINDOWED-INTENSITY-MEDIAN FM4-64","CELL WINDOWED-INTENSITY-MIN FM4-64","CELL WINDOWED-INTENSITY-STDDEV FM4-64")
start.time <- Sys.time()
final_dataframe <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(custom_headers), nrow =0))
colnames(final_dataframe) <- custom_headers
base_directory <- "F:/HCEMM/Tesztfeladat/HCEMM_project/test_files"

# Get a list of screen_X directories
screen_directories <- list.dirs(base_directory, full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE)

# Process each screen_X directory
for (directory in screen_directories) {
  # Get screen number from the directory name
  screen_number <- substr(basename(directory), nchar(basename(directory)), nchar(basename(directory)))
  
  # List all CSV files in the directory
  csv_files <- list.files(path = directory, pattern = "\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)
  
  # Process each CSV file and fill the dataframe
  for (file in csv_files) {
    # Extract information from the file name
    file_name <- basename(file)
    well <- gsub(".*_w([A-Za-z]+\\d+)_.*", "\\1", file_name)
    
    # Extract numeric part from "m" in the file name
    field_of_view <- as.numeric(gsub(".*_m(\\d+)_.*", "\\1", file_name))
    
    # Open the CSV file
    con <- file(file, "r")
    
    # Read the first line (header) and skip it
    header <- readLines(con, n = 1)
    
    # Read each line and merge with the row information
    while (length(line <- readLines(con, n = 1, warn = FALSE)) > 0) {
      # Split the line by commas (adjust the separator if needed)
      line_data <- unlist(strsplit(line, ","))
      
      # Combine information from the file name, directory, and line
      row_info <- c(file_name, screen_number, well, field_of_view)
      merged_row <- c(row_info, line_data)
      
      # Add the merged row to the final dataframe

      if (nrow(final_dataframe) == 0) {
        final_dataframe[1,] <- merged_row
      } else {
        final_dataframe <- rbind(final_dataframe, merged_row)
      }
    }
    
    # Close the file connection
    close(con)
  }
}
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Usually, the advice would be to use `data.table::fread`. However, your code seems to indicate that either these files are not proper CSV files or possibly corrupted somehow?